# How to create search data on bloc Flutter, exception (Exception: Exception occured: NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: android, flutter, webapi

I want integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET API. the problem is when I create search using bloc, i got this exception catch but i cannot caught an error. this is my error

```
_Exception (Exception: Exception occured: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_Map<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments.
Receiver: _Map len:5
Tried calling: map<listmodel>(Closure: (dynamic) => listmodel)
Found: map<Y0, Y1>((X0, X1) => MapEntry<Y0, Y1>) => Map<Y0, Y1> stackTrace: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      JobsState.getAllulistList (package:newprojectdesign_app/function/asearch.dart:49:47)
<asynchronous suspension>
)
```

and this is my code (the error got thrown here)

```
Future<List<listmodel>> getAllulistList() async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.data);
        List<listmodel> list1 = response.data.map<listmodel>((json) => listmodel.fromJsonn(json)).toList();
        return list1;
      } else {
        print("Error1");
        throw Exception('Error');
      }
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Error2");
      throw Exception("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
    }
  }
```

and i try to perform search here

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'All Users',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Search Bar to List of typed listmodel
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: TextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                suffixIcon: const InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                hintText: 'Search ',
              ),
              onChanged: (string) {
                _debouncer.run(() {
                  setState(() {
                    print("OnChangedAde: "+ ulist.length.toString());
                    userLists = ulist
                        .where(
                          (u) => (u.drainageid!.toLowerCase().contains(
                                string.toLowerCase(),
                              )),
                        )
                        .toList();

                    print("UserListCount: " + userLists.length.toString());
                  });
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              itemCount: userLists.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    side: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            userLists[index].drainageid!,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            userLists[index].rows![index].dateofinsp.toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

and this is my model gnerate from json to dart converter and i m modified a bit

```
class listmodel {
  String? drainageid;
  int? datacount;
  int? resultcount;
  String? page;
  List<Rows>? rows;
  String? error;

  listmodel(
      {this.drainageid,
      this.datacount,
      this.resultcount,
      this.page,
      this.rows});

  listmodel.withError(String errorMessage) {
    error = errorMessage;
  }

  listmodel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    drainageid = json['drainageid'];
    datacount = json['datacount'];
    resultcount = json['resultcount'];
    page = json['page'];
    if (json['rows'] != null) { rows = 
    (json['rows'] as List).map((e) => Rows.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList()..sort(
      (a, b) => b.dateofinsp!.compareTo(a.dateofinsp!));
     } 
  }

  factory listmodel.fromJsonn(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    var _rows;
    if (json['rows'] != null) { _rows = 
    (json['rows'] as List).map((e) => Rows.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList()..sort(
      (a, b) => b.dateofinsp!.compareTo(a.dateofinsp!));
     } 
    return listmodel(
    drainageid : json['drainageid'],
    datacount : json['datacount'],
    resultcount : json['resultcount'],
    page : json['page'],
    rows: _rows);
  }
    
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['drainageid'] = drainageid;
    data['datacount'] = datacount;
    data['resultcount'] = resultcount;
    data['page'] = page;
    if (rows != null) {
      data['rows'] = rows!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Rows {
  String? id;
  DateTime? dateoflastinsp;
  DateTime? dateofinsp;
  String? inspby;

  Rows({this.id, this.dateoflastinsp, this.dateofinsp, this.inspby});

  Rows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    dateoflastinsp = json['dateoflastinsp'] == null
          ? null
          : DateTime.parse(json['dateoflastinsp'] as String);
    dateofinsp = json['dateofinsp'] == null
          ? null
          : DateTime.parse(json['dateofinsp'] as String);
    inspby = json['inspby'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['dateoflastinsp'] = dateoflastinsp;
    data['dateofinsp'] = dateofinsp;
    data['inspby'] = inspby;
    return data;
  }
}
```

how to solve this error, i want to display the id and dateofinsp in listcardview